# Is better way to configure Windsor Castle for array of decorators

Tags: c#, arrays, castle-windsor, decorator

I have in my project interface

```
public interface IUpdater
{
    void Update();
}
```

and some implementations `UpdaterA, UpdaterB, UpdaterC`
I have also decorator `DecoratorUpdater`. All these classes implement interface `IUpdater` and I need configure Windsor Castle for using as array decorated implementations in class `UpdaterService`

My solution is following, but it not so easy how can be (currently I have 7 updaters and 2 decorators)

```
        // decorators
        Container.Register(
            Component.For<IUpdater, DecoratorUpdater>().LifestylePerWebRequest().Named("DecoratorUpdaterA").DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("underlyingUpdater", "NamedUpdaterA")),
            Component.For<IUpdater, DecoratorUpdater>().LifestylePerWebRequest().Named("DecoratorUpdaterB").DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("underlyingUpdater", "NamedUpdaterB")),
            Component.For<IUpdater, DecoratorUpdater>().LifestylePerWebRequest().Named("DecoratorUpdaterC").DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("underlyingUpdater", "NamedUpdaterC")));

        // updaters
        Container.Register(
            Component.For<IUpdater, UpdaterA>().LifestylePerWebRequest().Named("NamedUpdaterA"),
            Component.For<IUpdater, UpdaterB>().LifestylePerWebRequest().Named("NamedUpdaterB"),
            Component.For<IUpdater, UpdaterC>().LifestylePerWebRequest().Named("NamedUpdaterC"));

        // usages
        Container.Register(Component.For<UpdaterService>().ServiceOverrides(new
        {
            updaters = new[] 
            { 
                "DecoratedUpdaterA", 
                "DecoratedUpdaterB", 
                "DecoratedUpdaterC", 
            }
        }));
```

Is there better way how configure Windsor Castle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so better solution than mine isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Other a little bit shorter solution

```
        Container.Register(
            Component.For<IUpdater>().ImplementedBy<DecoratorUpdater>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IUpdater), typeof(UpdaterA))).Named("DecoratedUpdaterA").LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Component.For<UpdaterA>().ImplementedBy<UpdaterA>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Component.For<IUpdater>().ImplementedBy<DecoratorUpdater>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IUpdater), typeof(UpdaterB))).Named("DecoratedUpdaterB").LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Component.For<UpdaterB>().ImplementedBy<UpdaterB>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Component.For<IUpdater>().ImplementedBy<DecoratorUpdater>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IUpdater), typeof(UpdaterC))).Named("DecoratedUpdaterC").LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Component.For<UpdaterC>().ImplementedBy<UpdaterC>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to register lots of components at once.

For example we can register all of the IUpdator in assemblies in this application, making them all PerWebRequest and named what their implementation name is by the following:

```
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
                .BasedOn<IUpdator>()
                .Configure(registration => registration
                    .Named(registration.Implementation.Name)
                    .LifestylePerWebRequest()
                    ));
```

We can also have components receive all of the components of a particular type if we use the built in castle collection resolver.

If we have a class like this:

```
    public class DecoratedComponent : IComponentThatNeedsAnArrayOfDecorators
    {
        public DecoratedComponent(IDecorator[] decorators)
        {

        }
    }
```

We can resolve it like so:

```
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IComponentThatNeedsAnArrayOfDecorators>()
                .ImplementedBy<DecoratedComponent>());

        container.Resolve<IComponentThatNeedsAnArrayOfDecorators>();
```

Our decorated component will now have all of our decorators in it.

I can't exactly tell what you're attempting to do, but it feels like it can be cleaned up with methods like these.

Comment: I would like to write configuration more clearly. In solution in my question is easy to write error, because I used many constants of string.

Comment: If decorators have different interface, then is easy write automatic configuration, but than it isn't Decorator pattern. I need have implementations and decorators with same interface, I could set theirs dependecies independently of other code.